# Logging WCF Timeouts Server side

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, timeout

I want to be able to log WCF Timeouts that happen server side. I don't see any hooks that are helpful to me, or any automated way to let server timeouts be logged. Is there a way I can hook into WCF Calls to see when they are cancelled or timeouted, so I can log via AppInsights or log4net?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520356/5519709)

Comment: Thanks, already looked through that, didn't find an answer in there that helped me, or rather got anywhere close to logging or timeout hooks.

Comment: The WCF trace and IErrorhandler interfaces are used to catch and log server-side exceptions.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60190222/provide-exceptions-for-wcf-webhttpbinding/60220479#60220479
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging